# Reasign a drive letter with subst still shows wrong name

Tags: hard-drive, powershell, batch, subst

I created a `.ps1` script to mount a folder to the Drive `S`.
This works fine. When I reassign an other folder it still works but the name in the explorer wont be updated. But the correct folder is assign. (checked this by the available files after reassign).

I did this with the following script and just changed the path when i reassign an other folder:

```
subst s: /D
subst s: X:\folder1
```

So when I run the script for the first time to assign `TestFolder1` in the explorer this will be shown:

[image: Screenshot Explorer]

And when I run then the script again but to assign `TestFolder2` the `TestFolder2` will be assign to `S:` but the explorer will still show `TestFolder1` (just like in the screenshot)

Is there a way to update the name in explorer within the script? Or is this a settings issue?

Comment: What if you use PowerShell cmdlets for the task `New-PSDrive`/`Remove-PSDrive`/`Get-PSDrive`. Do they behave the same?

Answer (score 0):

You are not *refreshing* anything, you are in effect *removing* the
`s:` disk with the command `subst s: /D`.
Any Explorer instance that was showing the `s:` disk will terminate
immediately.

Your second `subst` command creates a new disk, and Explorer knows
immediately about it. But this is a new disk that has now to be
explored anew.

Comment: Yes i know. I do remove it to assign an other folder to s. And it works but the Explorer still Shows the Name of the old folder, but the new is correctly assignd

Comment: The only name I can see is `computer-name (S:)`. Perhaps you should add some screenshots to your post for explanation.

Comment: i tried to explain it with a screenshot in the question now.

Comment: I can't duplicate that. Which Windows version and how do you get Explorer to display this (I'm trying with *View > Tiles*)?

Comment: Windows 10 Version: 10.0.18363 Build 18363. Just Explorer --> This PC

Comment: Strange, but no go. I only get `disk-label (S:)`, where the label is of the real disk.